# What is the use of a synchronous callback function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I have been doing extensive reading on asynchronous programming for the web and use of callbacks in JavaScript and jQuery. I have understood the fundamentals of AJAX. What I cannot figure out is the use of callback functions when not used in asynchronous programming.

From my understanding, simply adding a callback to a function does not make it non-blocking/asynchronous. Asynchronous capability is actually provided by the environment (browser APIs). So adding a callback to a function that I have written will not lead to any asynchronous execution.

For example:

```
var X;
function Test(A, B, Callback) {
X=A+B*A*B;
Callback(X);
}

Test(99999,999999,function(Data) {
alert(Data);
});

alert("This is not printed first, as it would be in Async.");
```

In the above I'm taking two numbers and performing algebraic operations on them. Even though I'm using a callback function, the code execution will be blocked while the operations are performed. Then the callback will be executed, displaying an alert with the result of the computation. Then the next alert follows. Had I made an XMLHttpRequest instead of the algebraic operation, I would have got the second alert first because of asynchronous implementation. The code flow would not be blocked during the request as is happening during  the mathematical operation.

Thus, what is the use of a callback in non-async calls when code execution is blocked even with a callback?

Comment: The use of a callback function is to allow some configurable sub-logic to be performed within another function. It has nothing to do with async/sync. Asynchronous has to use a callback function to define what logic occurs when the asynchronous operation completes.

Comment: async can only be provided by the js API or DOM, or mocked using setTimeout, everything else is sync. Forcing an async pattern interaction would allow the workhorse to refactor itself into an async patter without touching the consumers, so it may be a case or planned expansion, or at least leaving open the potential for such. For example, some code part could rely on an in-ram cache for data now, and a use a database as more folks consume the service, without breaking the code implementing the data consuming functionality.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Why should I pass functions to a method if I can invoke the same from within it? Like with the array.foreach() method I can't understand the need for passing the callback function when I could iterate over the elements and within the loop pass each to a different function for processing.

Comment: @crush I want to talk to you regarding callbacks, can we have some chat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some very common examples of synchroneous callbacks are the methods on `Array.prototype`: `forEach`, `map`, `filter`, etc.

The role of the callback is to provide a partial implementation that can be easily swapped in a larger algorithm. Some design patterns like [template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) and [strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) come to mind.

Comment: Then, other than being an implementation of a design pattern it has no other significance in synchronous code?

Comment: Design patterns exist to solve problems. So if you generalize, synchronous callbacks solves problems. I pointed out two design patterns so you can see some specific kinds of problems that are solved by synchronous callbacks.

Comment: @Tibos I want to talk to you regarding callbacks in js, can we chat? I have some doubts

Answer (score 2):

You're right.
There is usually no reason to have a sync callback.

Exceptions include callbacks that might sometimes be async, or callbacks that can be raised more than once (eg, `[].map()`).

Comment: One very good reason to use a callback, other than with an asynchronous request, is to allow modular sub-logic within a function.

Comment: This is not true. Callbacks can be very usefull in sync context, just look at Array.prototype.filter and Array.prototype.map

Comment: @Ferenjito: The question is about async-style completion callbacks, not other callbacks like those.

Answer (score 0):

I use callbacks in the way you describe whenever I am working with complicated access methods which I don't want to rewrite, and I use them when I know the component will be run in a context the component doesn't know about, but am not particularly interested in developing or using an event emitter.

I do not know if other people find them as easy to work with as I do. So on a team, I try to get a sense of whether it is productive to use callbacks in the way you describe.